# url mapping and convert to dll in ASHX file

Tags: dll, ashx, url-mapping

1) i have a ashx file that pass to this file my parameters, for example :

```
<a href="UseCaseHandler.ashx?UC=EditProfile&Method=init">Edit</a>
```

now, i want use it as follows:

```
<a href="Handler/UC=EditProfile&Method=init">Edit</a>
```

2) how to convert ASHX file to dll file and how to use that??!!

tanx!

Answer (score 0):

The iis7 rewrite rules should work for you

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Rewrite">
<match url="^handler/uc=(.*)&amp;Method=(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="usecasehandler.ashx?uc={R:1}&amp;method={R:2}" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```